# IBM Function returning weird data back when calling REST API Endpoint

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I have an IBM Cloud Function like:

```
 return {'body': csv_output.getvalue(),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=dat.csv'}}
```

When called a public API endpoint it returns a csv file with right data.

But when I use postman to make a REST API endpoint call I get a weird result like:

```
{
    "annotations": [
        {
            "key": "exec",
            "value": "python:3.7"
        },
        {
            "key": "web-export",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "key": "final",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "key": "raw-http",
            "value": true
        }
    ],
    "exec": {
        "kind": "python:3.7",
        "code": "import
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Seems like I am getting code back rather than invoking the function.

[image]

Comment: Can you add details(request header, body etc.,) on how you are invoking the endpoint on Postman?

Comment: @VidyasagarMachupalli - I added image of what I am trying. Also when I directly input the rest api url and provide username/password it gives same result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using POSTMAN to return actions details (via the platform API), rather than invoking as a web action.

The HTTP endpoint for an action is `https://{APIHOST}/api/v1/namespaces/_/actions/<ACTION_NAME>`.

The HTTP endpoint for invoking an action as a web action is `https://{APIHOST}/api/v1/web/{QUALIFIED ACTION NAME}.{EXT}`.

Comment: Web Action works, the problem is with the REST API call.

Comment: You need send a POST request not a GET when invoking via API (rather than a web action)

Comment: I am not trying this in postman, currently just putting url directly into browser? Still returns weird data and if i put in .csv at the end it errors out.